# pip install Pillow on Alpine for Ipad freezes

Tags: python-imaging-library, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I am trying to install the Pillow pip package on Alpine for ipad via ISH. This is for light debugging purposes of a django project.
Since ISH already contains the apk package, some dependencies are installed doing the following:

```
apk update
apk upgrade
apk add python3

apk add py3-pip bash curl python3-dev gcc zlib-dev libffi-dev postgresql-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev

pip3 install virtualenv
```

and once the virtualenv activated:

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

The command freezes while building the wheel for the package and cannot install it. Is it a size limitation (42.5 MB for this package) or is there any missing dependencies I did not see?